# Menu item goes under the transparent image due to z-index issues

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this [jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/cRL7Z/).

```
<nav role="navigation" class="nav-main">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="menu-primary-navigation">
        <li class="active menu-home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-about-us"><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="menu-program"><a href="/program/">Program</a></li>
        <li class="menu-events"><a href="/events/">Events</a></li>
        <li class="menu-donate"><a href="/donate/">Donate</a></li>
        <li class="menu-contact"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>    
</nav>
```

As you can see, the "about us" link is no longer clickable because of the image placed on the left of it. I have played with different z-index values to no success.

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Please DO NOT link to external sites. Here is why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: You both are right. It's rather hard to recreate that scenario in jsfiddle (or something similar) as the overall html/css is rather complex. I'll edit the question to make it more clear and descriptive and remove the external link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution... Set "z-index:1000"

```
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation" style="z-index:1000;">
  <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active menu-home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-about-us"><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="menu-program"><a href="/program/">Program</a></li>
    <li class="menu-events"><a href="/events/">Events</a></li>
    <li class="menu-donate"><a href="/donate/">Donate</a></li>
    <li class="menu-contact"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept adding the z-index to the UL element instead. Your solution worked.